# Dart : Unhandled exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: http, dart, asynchronous, uri, future

When i use `['name']` to print the name from json http link i get this error:

```
Unhandled exception:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

The code is:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  print(getData());
}

Future<http.Response?> getData() {
  return http
      .get(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"))
      .then((http.Response response) {
    var a = jsonDecode(response.body)['name'];
    print(a);
  });
}
```

Comment: The returned JSON is a list of objects. It does not make any sense to query "name" directly on this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON response is in a list format. You will need to select one of the object from that list to use the `['name']` selector.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  var response = getData();
  for (var person in reponse) {
    print(person['name']);
  }
}

Future<http.Response?> getData() {
  return http
      .get(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"))
      .then((http.Response response) {
    var a = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(a);

    // Select one of the items here. This case we're selecting the first one.
    var name = a[0]['name'];
    print(name);

    return a;
  });
}
```

Comment: but  how if we need to print all names from every id

Comment: I updated the code. I didn't test it, so you may need to slightly tweak it. Basically, the response is returned to the main function. There, you are able to iterate over the response items.

Comment: @MuhammadTawil did this solution work for you?

Comment: yes this work , thank you , but i dont know how to print all names from every id ,but this work to solve this error